# Creating vector of tensorflow nodes efficiently

Tags: python, tensorflow

Lets say I have the following function in python, that gets tensorflow variable x and some constant y and as output it returns node, that depends in some way on those two.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(3.0)
y = {"a" : 3, "b" : 1.0}

def make_graph(x, y): 
    return y["a"] * x**2 + y["b"]
```

I have a list of constants like y (y_vec) and I would like to apply the function to each element and then calculate sum of these nodes, something like this:

```
f = sum([ make_graph(x, y) for y in y_vec ])
```

Then I want to optimize f with respect to x. Of course the function make_graph can be more complicated. The question is how to do this efficiently for a very long y_vec.

Comment: What do you mean more efficiently? You can group all the additions into one with [`tf.sum_n`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_n). Is that the problem, or is it that you have a very large number of constants and don't want to create nodes for each one? In that case it would depend on the function, but it would probably involve some broadcasting operation and [`tf.reduce_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum).

Comment: @jdehesa The problem is, as you write, that I have a very large number of constants and don't want to create node for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the function that you are applying. In your example, you could do something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(3.0)
y = {"a" : [3, 4, 5], "b" : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]}

def make_graph(x, y): 
    return tf.reduce_sum(y["a"] * x**2 + y["b"], axis=0)

f = make_graph(x, y)
```

Comment: So basically I should write the function in such a way that all the operations can be called on vectors instead of scalars in the first place?

Comment: @JosefOndrej Exactly, what they sometimes call "vectorize" a function or expression (although the [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) in NumPy is a convenience wrapper for what is essentially a for loop, so the term can be misleading).